# My form button needs to be clicked twice for the form to show error / success message

Tags: javascript, phpmailer, form-submit, event-listener, contact-form

I made a contact form with html, css, JavaScript and with php mailer as backend that is sending form info to my e-mail and google spreadsheet.

My form submits successfully every time, but I need to click the submit button twice for the success message.

the Git repository with the full code:
https://github.com/FranjoDumanovsky/Bar-crawl-zagreb

[main JS file](https://github.com/FranjoDumanovsky/Bar-crawl-zagreb/blob/main/js/mail.js)

Appreciate every little help.

**Submit Function**

```
function submitForm() {
  if (nameInputValidation && emailInputValidation && numberOfPeopleValidation && phoneInputValidation && isChecked && foundAboutUsValidation) {
    submissionAlert.classList.add("show");
    successMessage.classList.add("show");
    const scriptURL = "[GOOGLE-SCRIPT]";
    fetch(scriptURL, { method: "POST", body: new FormData(form) })
      .then(successMessage.classList.add("show"))
      .catch(errorMessage.classList.add("show"));

// Send data to PHP script with AJAX request
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "./phpmailer/index.php", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    successMessage.classList.add(".show");
  } else {
    errorMessage.classList.add(".show");
  }
};

// Get form data
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
var dateFor = document.getElementById("date-for").value;
var phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value;
var numberOfPeople = document.getElementById("numberOfPeople").value;
var foundAboutUs = document.getElementById("foundAboutUs").value;

xhr.send(
  "name=" +
    name +
    "&email=" +
    email +
    "&message=" +
    message +
    "&phoneNumber=" +
    phoneNumber +
    "&date-for=" +
    dateFor +
    "&numberOfPeople=" +
    numberOfPeople +
    "&foundAboutUs=" +
    foundAboutUs
);
phoneInput.parentElement.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    checkInputs();
  }
}
```

**HTML Form without unnecessary inputs**

```
<form name="contact-form" class="contact" id="contact-form" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); submitForm();">
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-btn">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

I have tried many different things such as

-> Putting `onSubmit="event.preventDefault(); submitForm();"` on form
-> putting `onClick="onSubmit('event)"` on button element, having event prevent default on function.
-> Event listener having anonymous function handling the submit code
->Event listener for button having Click event, or for Form having onSubmit event.

When I made it so it needs to be clicked once, the error & success messages wouldn't show because the prevent default wouldn't work i guess.
In case it didn't refresh the page, the button would have to be clicked twice

I tried using some stackOverflow anwsers, but I haven't had any luck with it. It either has to be clicked twice, or the preventDefault doesn't work and the page refreshes before error / success messages.

Answer (score 1):

When I check your main JS file I see that you implemented the fetch() request wrong.

Here is your code on line 185:

```
fetch(scriptURL, { method: "POST", body: new FormData(form) })
      .then(successMessage.classList.add("show"))
      .catch(errorMessage.classList.add("show"));
```

Here is how you should implement fetch:

```
fetch(scriptURL, { method: "POST", body: new FormData(form) })
  .then(response => {
    if(response.ok) {
      successMessage.classList.add("show");
    } else {
      throw new Error('Form submission failed');
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    errorMessage.classList.add("show");
  });
```

with the event.preventDefault() function added to the top of your submitForm() function.

You've also wrongly implemented the classList.add() on line 195 and 197. Here is your code:

```
        successMessage.classList.add(".show");
        errorMessage.classList.add(".show");
```

Remove the dots before the "show".

Next, you've created an XMLHttpRequest and defined its onreadystatechange function. But you've done this after you've opened the request. The onreadystatechange function might not work as expected because of this. You should rearrange the order from this

```
xhr.open("POST", "./phpmailer/index.php", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {...};
```

to this

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {...};
xhr.open("POST", "./phpmailer/index.php", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

See if these changes can solve your issue.

Comment: You nailed it perfectly! Good job

Comment: I have corrected the mistakes you pointed out. I am very grateful for the response. However the problem has not been fixed. Now it even takes more time after double clicking submit button until error / success message appears. I will update the changes to the github repository if your interested to check if I did in fact do it the right way.

Comment: I also got this response on reddit: 

"i feel its because the success message rendering succeeds the promise resolution for the api call. ive faced the same where there’s a strange delay and i need to trigger another event on the page for the promise resolution. i havent found a stable solution by try removing the then chain and instead using a simple conditional that renders the message if any data was returned from the fetch request"